# ZPL Won't Print Y >= 90

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I just have some simple ZPL to print out a test and what I've come to notice is that setting the y-coordinate to anything 90 or above won't print. The printer feeds out paper but it's blank.

If I set the y-coordinate to something below 90 it will print. This is going to be a major issue for me as I need to print multiple lines and can't have them overlap.

```
"^XA^FO20,100^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a ZPL test.^FS^XZ"
```

Comment: what is your label length set to?

Comment: I wasn't setting the label length but I just tried adding '^LL1200' and still didn't print

Comment: send ^xa^hh^xz and post response here